# How to get multiple user input variable as a specific defined data type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I take multiple user input data for specific data type?

For example in PYTHON 3.xx:

```
int(input(varl))   # or 
float(input(varl)) # for to take only one single input

varl0 = [varl0 for varl0 in input("Enter multiple values: ").split()]
```

Similarly for taking multiple variables (specific data type) input from the user:

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.  Just try this one for `int` numbers (as a integer list):

If you want `float` - then just change `int` to `float` in the List Compression.

```
nums = [int(num) for num in input("Enter multiple integer numbers: ").split()]            # convert string to int by `int(num)`
```

Enter multiple integer numbers: 1 2 3 4 5

```
# Output after running:

print(nums)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```